# PHP - PHPMailer - how to add file as attachment with correct extension

Tags: php, email, upload, phpmailer

I am building a website and have a form wherein the user can enter some fields, i.e. name, email, etc. but then also has the option to upload a file. I am using PHPMailer to construct an email that has the user's data as the email fields, and then sends it to me, so I can look at it. All works fine until the file upload. I am relatively new to PHP so it might be something little, but its driving me crazy. In the code below, I generate a new name for the uploaded file, and then append the file extension. Then I move it to a temp folder and try to attach it to the email via `$mail->addAttachment`. The email sends and everything, but the attached file has no extension--and when I manually download and add the appropriate extension, it works, but for some reason the file wont attach as the proper type.

```
    // if one of the fields is set they all will be, i.e. the form has been submitted
    if (isset($_POST['firstName']))
    {
    // array to hold possible runtime errors
    $errors = array();

    // if statement to see if user failed to enter one of the required fields
    if (empty($_POST['firstName']) || empty($_POST['lastName']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['subject'])
    || empty($_POST['message']) || empty($_POST['phone']))
    {
    array_push($errors, 'Please enter all required fields');
    }


    // var to keep track of whether or not we have a file
    $have_file = ($_FILES['inputFile']['error'] != UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE);

    //checks for file upload as well
    if ($have_file)
    {
    // here a file has been uploaded, so we make sure its an acceptable type
    $ext_whitelist = array('dwg', 'asm', 'acp', '3dxml', 'cgr', 'dft', 'dxf', 'iam', 'idw', 'ipt', 'ipn', 'par', 'prt',
    'skp', 'rvt', 'rfa',' sldasm', 'slddrw', 'sldprt', 'step', 'stl');

    // var to store file array
    $file = $_FILES['inputFile'];

    // file properties stored for easier readability
    $file_name = $file['name'];
    $file_tmp = $file['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $file['size'];
    $file_error = $file['error'];

    // get file extension
    $file_ext = explode('.', $file_name);
    $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));


    if (!in_array($file_ext, $ext_whitelist))
    {
        if ($ext == 'php')
        {
            array_push($errors, 'Nice try');;
        }
        else
        {
            array_push($errors, 'Please enter a valid file type');
        }
    }


    // checks file size
    if ($file_size > 64000000)
    {
        array_push($errors, 'File too large, please call for further information');
    }
    }


    // if we have an error, we just output that, or those, otherwise, we proceed
    // with mailer
    if (!empty($errors))
    {
    foreach ($errors as $err) { ?>

        <p class="text-center" style="margin-top:20px;font-size:16px;">

            <?php echo $err; ?>

        </p>

    <?php
    }

    }
    // if here, there have been no errors
    else
    {
    require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    //mail server setup
    $mail->isSMTP();                                    // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                     // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                             // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = '';         // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = '';                     // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                          // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                  // TCP port to connect to

    //add To and From fields
    $mail->From = '';
    $mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
    $mail->addAddress('');

    $mail->isHTML(true);                                // Set email format to HTML


    //add message contents
    $mail->Subject = $_POST['subject'];

    $mail->Body = $_POST['message'] . '<br><br>' . $_POST['firstName'] . ' ' . $_POST['lastName'] . '<br>' . $_POST['phone'];

    // adds organization if its there
    if (!empty($_POST['organization']))
    {
        $mail->Body .= '<br>' . $_POST['organization'];
    }

    // uploads/attaches file if there was one
    if($have_file)
    {
        // give file unique name and set its destination as a temporary folder
        $file_name_new = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_ext;
        $file_destination = sys_get_temp_dir() . '\\' . $file_name_new;

        if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination))
        {
            echo $file_destination;
            $mail->addAttachment($file_destination, 'Uploaded file');
        }
        else
        {
            ?>
            <p class="text-center" style="margin-top:20px;font-size:16px;">Error sending message, please call and let us know</p>
            <?php
        }
    }

    //send the message
    if (!$mail->send())
    {
        ?>
        <p class="text-center" style="margin-top:20px;font-size:16px;">Error sending message, please call and let us know</p>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <p class="text-center" style="margin-top:20px;font-size:16px;">Message sent! Thank you for visiting us today</p>
        <?php
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have left certain fields empty to prevent showing my info. i.e. `$mail->From`

Comment: You could just follow [the example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps). You could also look at the [documentation for `addAttachment()`](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#method_addAttachment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Hanoncs I managed to get it I think. The line:

```
$mail->addAttachment($file_destination, 'Uploaded file');
```

was renaming the file upon attachment to 'Uploaded file', literally. So, obviously, in the email there was no file extension on the file, because of the name. So all I had to do was change 'Uploaded file' to something with the extension, e.g. 'uploadedfile.ext' and it seemed to work. A silly, but enormously frustrating mistake, since all of the file upload handling seemed to work rather well. So the block now looks like this:

```
    // uploads/attaches file if there was one
    if($have_file)
    {
    // give file unique name and set its destination as a temporary folder
    $file_name_new = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_ext;
    $file_destination = sys_get_temp_dir() . '\\' . $file_name_new;

    if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination))
    {
        echo $file_destination;
        $mail->addAttachment($file_destination, 'uploadedFile.dwg');
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <p class="text-center" style="margin-top:20px;font-size:16px;">Error sending message, please call and let us know</p>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Anyway, thanks for all your help, especially about the IDE, going to work on setting that up now.

Answer (score 1):

First I would say you need to debug and check the file_ext at the time its appended and make sure its not empty.

To get the file extension use:

```
$file_ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Let me know your result and I can assist further.

Comment: I think I tried that too, it still gives me the same string, 'txt' for example, which I then try to append to $file_name_new, and attach, but it still shows up in my inbox as an extension-less file. Is there something wrong with my file upload syntax/logic?

Comment: You think you tried it? That is the proper way to do it in php. You need to debug and check the $file_ext when you create the variable and then check the $file_name_new after you create the variable. Debugging is your best friend. What IDE are you using?

Comment: unfortunately no ide, just notepad++. When you say debug on variable creation, you mean create $file and $file_tmp, and then grab the file extension from $file_tmp, and validate there? is that any different from doing the validation where I do it?

Comment: WOW, do not program without a proper IDE. go here https://netbeans.org/downloads/ and download the version you want. Then you can place what is called 'breakpoints', those allow you to watch as your program executes and you can see the variables as they get their value, you can actually see what is inside each variable so you would easily see if the file ext is getting created properly.

Comment: ok thank you very much, I'll get that set up and report back!

Comment: and the conventional way to it is-- 1) validate file type 2) generate new file name 3) create new file name/temp directory 4) move file from php tmp directory 5) attach to email?

Comment: Yes, its not popular but the proper way. Most people don't know it exists.

Comment: unfortunately, I cannot seem to get NetBeans to connect to the XDebug session, even having changed the ini file and everything on my local wamp server, I might have to stick with debugging by putting echo statements in my page as a I go. I have found that the file is moved successfully to the tmp directory to the directory given by sys_get_temp_dir() -- extension and all. It just seems to be when i try to attach the file from that directory where it kind of self-edits things.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83057/discussion-between-ben-granger-and-hanoncs).

Comment: You need to download xdebug... I promise it will make development way easier.

Comment: Hahahaha sure, it wasn't an attempt at an answer.